# Cannot set volume accurately

Tags: python, pygame

So today, while I was trying to create a music player using Tkinter with pygame, I noticed something weird. When I tried changing the volume of my player, it was not setting it up accurately. So what the problem is, when I tried to set the volume to `0.9`, it ended up putting it to `0.8984375`. I have no idea how these two numbers are related. And when I tried to set it to `0.8`, it set the volume to `0.796875`. But it worked when I put it to `0.5`, which means it only works for 0.5 accurately. I have tried every possible way to overcome this, but nothing helped.

So anyone got any idea what is wrong with my pygame? The part of the code which I use to set up the volume is given below:

*Note: I have already initiated pygame mixer. Here, the parameter self refers to my player's main class and event is used for my keybinds.*

```py
def decVol(self,event):
            d = mixer.music.get_volume()
            print(d) # d is 1.0 now!
            mixer.music.set_volume(0.9)
            print(mixer.music.get_volume()) # Prints as 0.8984375 <--- -_-
```

I am not providing the rest of the codes since it is useless to reproduce this situation and is working fine (Just some labels and stuff). This is the only part that handles volume. And as far as I know, I think it's something on my computer's end. Well, I'm on windows 10 x64, btw. If you know something about this, please suggest some better ways to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The precision is lost due to the internal representation of volume in `pygame`.

From `pygame` [source code](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/blob/d31eae2c804592a1b1875122c139e209055fa90e/src_c/mixer.c#L711),

```c
    Mix_VolumeChunk(chunk, (int)(volume * 128));
```

the volume is multiplied by 128 and cast to a C `int`. Then, it goes through the reverse process when you retrieve the volume.

```c
    return PyFloat_FromDouble(volume / 128.0);
```

`int(128 * 0.9) / 128` gives you exactly `0.8984375`. I don' think there's much you can do about it in Python.

Comment: Oh! This works weirdly... right? So is there some way or anything you could suggest to me to make it precisely a float number like `0.9,0.8,0.7 etc...` or are you sure it's impossible? Because I'm planning to show the current vol in my player, I think it's a bad and weird way to show it, like `0.98646...` instead of `0.9` or `0.9*100`, so I get  something like `90` to show..

Comment: @The_Coder Maybe you could represent it as a slider between 0 and 18 with increments of 0.1, or some multiple of that?

Comment: Yep, I have a slider already for that, and it's working great with it. But this one is for setting sound via keyboard "up and down arrow keys."

Comment: @The_Coder I don't think you can do it without precision loss. You can always interpolate 0-128 to 0-100 for nicely displayed numbers. (Hopefully, the user won't notice their volume is off by less than 0.01%.)

Comment: Ahh yes. I will try interpolating then. Thanks for your time and help. I gained so much knowledge in a short time. :)